# Invalid literal for Float error in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, sklearn-pandas

I am trying to use sklearn and perform linear regression in Python using sklearn library.

This is the code I have used to train and fit the model, I am getting the error when I run the predict function call.

```
train, test = train_test_split(h1, test_size = 0.5, random_state=0)

my_features = ['bedrooms', 'bathrooms', 'sqft_living', 'sqft_lot', 'floors', 'zipcode']
trainInp = train[my_features]

target = ['price']
trainOut = train[target]

regr = LinearRegression()

# Train the model using the training sets

regr.fit(trainInp, trainOut)

print('Coefficients: \n', regr.coef_)

testPred = regr.predict(test)
```

After fitting the model, when I try to predict using the test data, it throws the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/gouta/PycharmProjects/MLCourse1/Python.py", line 52, in <module>
    testPred = regr.predict(test)
  File "C:\Users\gouta\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py", line 200, in predict
    return self._decision_function(X)
  File "C:\Users\gouta\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py", line 183, in _decision_function
    X = check_array(X, accept_sparse=['csr', 'csc', 'coo'])
  File "C:\Users\gouta\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 393, in check_array
    array = array.astype(np.float64)
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 20140604T000000
```

The coefficients for the Linear Regression Model are

```
('Coefficients: \n', array([[ -5.04902429e+04,   5.23550164e+04,   2.90631319e+02,
         -1.19010351e-01,  -1.25257545e+04,   6.52414059e+02]]))
```

The following is the first five lines of the test dataset

[image: Test dataset]

Is the error being caused because of the large value of coefficients? How to fix this?

Comment: WHy is there the letter `T` in the value?  Also, consider showing some of your code...

Comment: Please show us the code that actually throws the error.

Comment: Can you show the first few rows of `test`?

Comment: "Is the error being caused because of the large value of coefficients?" <- No, the error is almost certainly because you've got something that looks like a date/time column in your test data, when the model is expecting just an array of floats. *Please* show us the first few rows of the test data!

Comment: I am sorry. The mistake I made was, I had selected a number of columns for the train input and target, but had all the columns in the test dataset, so there were additional variables in the test dataset that caused the problem.

Comment: @goutam: No problem; it happens. That was what I suspected, but it's much easier to tell when the question includes the code and a data sample.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Kinda new to StackOverflow. I am clear now on how to post questions. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're fitting the model on a selected set of features from the whole dataframe (you do `trainInp = train[my_features]`), but you're trying to predict on the complete set of features (`regr.predict(test)`), including non-numeric features like `date`.

So instead of doing `regr.predict(test)`, you should do `regr.predict(test[my_features])`. More generally, remember that whatever preprocessing you apply to the training set (normalization, feature selection, PCA, ...), you should also apply to the test set.

Alternatively, you could cut down to the set of features of interest before you do the train-test split:

```
my_features = ['bedrooms', 'bathrooms', ...]
train, test = train_test_split(h1[my_features], test_size = 0.5, random_state=0)
```

Comment: Thank you Mark. Just realised that and commented that.